# is git diff porcelain output unambigous for newlines?

Tags: git, diff

I tried `git diff --word-diff=porcelain` to see what the output is like. I'd like to use it to see word changes and also to identify generic changes in the file.

I removed one line completely from the input file and here's the result:

```
~
 if (array_key_exists("map", $_GET))
~
 {
~
-  $map = $_GET["map"];
~
 
~
   $map_info = get_map_info($map);
~
 
~
```

As you can see the removed line `$map = $_GET["map"];` is there with a dash sign before it, so that is good.

However, in the diff output ~ character indicates newlines and there is a still a ~ line after the removed line, though the complete line was removed, so the diff output should indicate a removed newline too somehow.

How does this diff show that the newline character after `$map = $_GET["map"];` was also removed?

Comment: "there is a still a ~ line after the removed line" No there isn't. There is an empty line and _its_ newline, but the newline associated with the deleted line is gone.

Comment: There are two tilde characters after the removed line in the diff. In the file there is only one empty line (newline) after the removed line before the next `$map_info = get_map_info($map);` begins.

Comment: Plain `git diff` *is* reliably machine parseable; `git diff --word-diff` is *not*.